# Laravel Session Time Out Remaining

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There's a variety of answers regarding detecting IF the session has timed out. I am NOT asking that.

I am asking, **how can I tell exactly how much time is remaining the user's Laravel session.**

Assume I am using the latest version of Laravel.

I am strongly interested in knowing what the Laravel subsystem thinks is the time left remaining before it's native/built-in session timeout expires.

I am strongly against rolling my own, or creating my own custom timer of any sort.

Not that it matters, but my session lifetime setting configuration (session.php) looks like this (below). And my .ENV setting is also SESSION_LIFETIME=10.

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 10),
```

Comment: You can pass value of TTL every page load in variable. If that is the question.

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: @Paras "database"

Comment: Adding to my answer, for database driver, just checkout the `last_activity` column value in the `sessions` table and use the formula provided in my answer to calculate remaining time

Answer (score 3):

This question is very specific to the session handler in use. If you need to know the time remaining before it expires, you must calculate it manually depending on the session handler like so:

1. File session handler: `remaining time = last modified timestamp of file + session lifetime - current timestamp`
2. Cookie session handler: `remaining time = cookie expiry time - current time`
3. Database session handler: `remaining time = last_activity column value in session table + session lifetime - current timestamp`
4. Cache session handler: `remaining time = cache ttl`

The session drivers use different session handler implementations as follows:

1. Cookie driver: Cookie session handler
2. File driver: File session handler
3. Database driver: Database session handler
4. APC: Cache session handler
5. Memcached: Cache session handler
6. Redis: Cache session handler

Comment: Since I am using Database session handler, how is last_activity column exposed to me in code?

Comment: The session handler interface does not have a method to calculate remaining time. Therefore, it is not exposed. You may make a model and access the sessions table through Eloquent